# Multiple DataBases with one class

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio

I'm trying to connect to some databases. I'm using one class to connect to my connection string with this code:

```
    private static BaseDados instance;
    public static BaseDados Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance == null)
                instance = new BaseDados();
            return instance;
        }
    }
    private string strLigacao;
    private MySqlConnection ligacaoBD;

    public BaseDados()
    {
        //ligação à`enter code here` bd
        strLigacao = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["empresaA"].ToString();
        ligacaoBD = new MySqlConnection(strLigacao);
        ligacaoBD.Open();
    }
```

And then I'm changing the connection string with:

```
            Configuration configuration = System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~");
            var section = (ConnectionStringsSection)configuration.GetSection("connectionStrings");
            section.ConnectionStrings["empresaB"].ConnectionString = @"Server=localhost;Database=" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString() + " ;Uid=root;Pwd=Qwerty!123;";
            configuration.Save();
            Response.Redirect("**********");
```

Well, this method only supports one database at the same time, because someone said to me this is a singleton.
Someone knows how to change this to support multiple databases?

Comment: What is your requirement multiple database instances at the same time or multiple database between runs? The web configuration can be changed by editing the respective configuration in IIS (assuming you are using IIS) However if you need to connect to 2 different databases in the same instance then what you will need to change is different.

Comment: yeh , im understanding... i will remove the instance and pass the string connection to the constructor as a variable to the user change it.
Thanks , i will try that :D